# See indices implicitly created for foreign key constraints in MySQL

Tags: mysql, indexing, foreign-keys, innodb

When I add a foreign key constraint to my table, `SHOW INDEX` doesn't show any new indices, but the overall space used by the indices in that table increases. Apparently, the index for the field I put a constraint on does get created implicitly, but MySQL doesn't want me to tell about its existence. Is there a way to see those implicit indices anyway?

The table type is InnoDB.